# Using for loop in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, for-loop

i have this script in shell bash:

```
top | awk '{$10 $11}'> agent.csv
top | awk '{$10 $11}'> spark.csv
top | awk '{$10 $11}'> kafka.csv
top | awk '{$10 $11}'> zk.csv
top | awk '{$10 $11}'> engine.csv

for ((;;))
do
        top -b -c -d 2 n 10 | grep agent >> agent.csv;
        top -b -c -d 2 n 10 | grep spark >> spark.csv
        top -b -c -d 2 n 10 | grep kafka >> kafka.csv
        top -b -c -d 2 n 10 | grep zookeeper >> zk.csv
        top -b -c -d 2 n 10 | grep engine >> engine.csv
        sleep 10;
done &
```

what I am trying to do with the 'awk' command before the loop is to have the name of the metrics %CPU and %MEM.
inside the loop I am trying to get specific processes
then put them inside a file each file for each process

I am not getting what I want to get. 
nothing is being written to the files.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to achieve with the first top. you will have all the column 10 and 11 of the top, with the headers (zombie, load average, etc). In addition, your `awk` command does not print anything so you will not have any result, it should be something like : `awk '{print $10" "$11}'`

Comment: If what you want to achieve is to have a header in your files corresponding to the one of the top command, you should try something like : 

`top -b -n 1 |grep "PID USER" |tee agent.csv spark.csv kafka.csv zk.csv engine.csv`

Answer (score 0):

`top` runs endlessly. If you want to run it only once then use option `-n` to specify the number of iterations like you have already done inside your for loop. Additionally enabling batch mode with option `-b` is also useful: `top -b -n 1`.

Note that a single iteration doesn't return the *current* CPU usage of all processes but the average CPU usage since their start.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following command:

top -n 1 | grep -e CPU -e MEM | awk '{print $10" "$11}' > agent.csv

top -n 1 prints out only 1 top output rather than periodically refreshing every 1 second(default).

grep searches the ROWs of output for 2 patterns CPU and MEM(multiple expression search is done using the -e option). When it is found, which will be the row 0 of top output, it is passed as input to awk statement.

awk statement then prints only the CPU and MEM columns into your file.